# python PIL acces multiple images from a single image file

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have written a python script to Delta compress an image. The image file format is .tif which contains 8 images. When I use the normal code ...

```
org_Image = Image.open(image)
org_Data = org_Image.load()
```

... I can only access the first image. How do I go about accessing the other ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `org_Image.seek(org_Image.tell() + 1)` to get the next one.

In PIL `seek` moves you to a given frame, (with an IO_Error if it doesn't exist), and tell `reports` the current frame number.